# XGraphics Draw String from end of string

Tags: c#, wpf, pdfsharp

I am drawing two strings on top of each other like so:

```
gfx.DrawString("Complete Total (Ex VAT) £" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", totalCompletePrice), new XFont(roboto, 10 * 4, XFontStyle.Regular), XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(2445, 2225));
gfx.DrawString(header + " Total (Ex VAT) £" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", totalCompletePrice), new XFont(roboto, 10 * 4, XFontStyle.Regular), XBrushes.Black, new XPoint(2445, 2295));
```

But my problem is they are not in line with the end of the document. I can't figure out a way to draw these strings starting from the end. So the £1,000.55 is always inline with each other.

Example:

```
This is a really long header total £999.99
          Complete Total (Ex VAT) £9999.99
```

I want to get it so the prices are inline with each other. Is there a way to specific the end coordinate of the string placement and draw it backwards? so it starts at the end of the string and draws the rest from that point. I tried the Measure string function but it didn't seem to work properly.

I tried `End X co-ord - text length` but it didn't align them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try a variant of `XGraphics.DrawString` that takes an `XStringFormat` parameter and specify e.g. `XStringFormats.TopRight` or another right-aligned option.

You can also use the `XTextFormatter` class. A demo that shows right-aligned text can be found here:
http://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TextLayout-sample.ashx

Comment: They are not implemented yet.

Comment: As far as I can tell after a quick glance into the source code, they are implemented in the WPF build version 1.50. I didn't check other versions for the time being.